# proving that the probability of the intersection of 2 events is greater or equal than the multiplication of probabilities

Tags: probability, independence

I am given the following data about two random variables that are declared on the same variable space:
$P(X = x \cap Y = y) \le P(X = x)P(Y = y) $ for all x,y

The question is, are they independent?

The solution is yes, without any other assumptions. So I assume the way of proving this is by proving the other side of the inequality. I would like some help proving this, or another way of proving the statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to assume that the above inequality is true for all possible $x$ and $y$ (otherwise the result isn't true).

Hint: What can you say about $\sum\limits_{x,y}P(X=x\cap Y=y)$?

Comment: Ah, I think I have an idea. the sum equals 1 from the law of total probability. So you multiply say $ P(X = x_0) (\sum_{y \in  R} P(Y = y)) $ and the sum equals 1 so if one of the multiplications is smaller than the intersection, the sum is smaller than 1 from the given inequality. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's right, the only way to satisfy the law of total prob is your inequality is actually an equality for every $x,y$.